# Where can I find a railgun in gta 5

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I looked at the plane crash site in sandy shores not there and then I tried to do that trick at ammunitions shooting range it was not there

Answer (score 0):

You can only get the railgun if you have the returning user bonus (the one you get when you move from x360 to x1 or x1 to pc etc.), if you have the bonus, then it should be available in every gun store.

Comment: So, for an actual new player, would it be possible to (for example) take a copy of GTAV for PS3 (used, borrowed, whatever), start a new game, quit the game as early as possible, then start the game up on PS4 (with the same PSN account and RSC account)? Would that get the unlock, or is some amount of actual play time required?

Comment: @recognizer it would work, but you'd need to go to online first or smth if I remember correctly.